# redirect through a form without giving an error

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I'm trying to send visitors to http://www.facebook.com/plugins/comments.php?href=http://google.com?c

keeps giving error
The comments plugin requires an href parameter.

```
<script>
function go(){
    var uri = 'http://www.facebook.com/plugins/comments.php?href=' 
        + encodeURIComponent('http://google.com?c');

    window.frames[0].document.body.innerHTML = 
        '<form target="_parent" action="' 
        + uri 
        + '"></form>';
    window.frames[0].document.forms[0].submit();
}    
</script>
<iframe onload="window.setTimeout('go()', 99)" src="about:blank" style="visibility:hidden"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is by default, `form` elements submit with `GET`, therefore any parameters you have in your `action` attribute will be stripped.

The fix is simple: `method="post"`

```
'<form target="_parent" method="post" action="' + uri + '"></form>'
```

Working demo: *http://jsfiddle.net/MkBAP/*